# mootools implementing a Node class with hide and protected properties

Tags: javascript, mootools

I wanted to implement a Node type like written below but I want to hide or protect the properties which aren't functions so they can't be over written from outside the class. Is this possible with Mootools hide and protect properties? and what is the difference between hide and protect in Mootools?

```
var Node = new Class({

    initialize : function(name){
        this.globalId = container.globalId++;
        this.name = name || 'unnamed Node';
    },

    globalId : null,

    siblingId : null,

    name : null,

    parentNode: null,

    childrenNodes : [],

    addChild : function(child){
        //ensure it is a Node object
        if(!instanceOf(child,Node)){
            throw new Exception('Not a Node',this.name+':\nNode.globalId = '+this.globalId+
            "\nAttempting to add a child node that is not a 'Node' type!");
        }
        child.parentNode = this;
        child.siblingId = this.children.length;
        this.children.push(child);
    },

    removeChild : function(child){
        //ensure the child is my child!
        if(child.parentNode !== this){
            throw new Exception('Lost Child',this.name+':\nNode.globalId = '+this.globalId+
            "\nAttempting to remove Node:\n"+child.name+":\nNode.globalId = "+child.globalId);
        }
        this.childrenNodes.splice(child.siblingId,1);
    }

});
Node.globalId = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need hidden properties, you can get them like this:

```
var Node = (function() { 
    var someProperty; // This variable and any others you create here are available only inside this function's scope

    return new Class({
        // You have access to those variables here
    });
}()); // call the function immediately. It returns your new class.
```

Comment: thanks, I know how to make variables private using closures like that, I was just wondering whether Mootools had a method in the API for doing this within a class definition. I had seen that they have Function.prototype.hide() and Function.prototype.protect() functions which change the variable $hidden and $protected to true but I wasn't sure how to use these.

Comment: not really. using a closure is the only acceptable pattern for having private variables. you can expose some accessors from within your class definition that either read or write to the variable but there is no way to protect any property that is being returned by the class constructor - all it does is give you a specially crafted object with wrapped methods (when functions). it cannot wrap static object properties. `Node.globalId = 0;` also just uses the Object for storage - you want to consider `Node.prototype.globalId` or `NodeInstance.globalId`.

Comment: if you have `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` available in your browser, you can do stuff like this to protect yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/uuxSX/

Comment: Correction: "if your users have `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` available in their browsers..." In other words, you probably can't use this. Yet.

Comment: there is also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty so support is not that bad